# Where can I find open data for psychology research on meditation?

Tags: psychology, meditation

I would like to know how I can get free access to data obtained from psychological experiments conducted to study the effects of meditation on the brain. Ex : FMRI data and the like

Comment: Contact the researchers that performed the studies that are found by web-search ‘fmri meditation’.

Answer (score 1):

Kaggle has a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/abyssjumper/meditation-eegdata) of an EEG conducted on a meditation group versus a control.

Other than that, if you are looking for the raw datasets of fmri meditation studies, that may be a little more difficult. If you are fine with summary statistics, and some inferential tests (data that has already been analysed), then [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.za/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=meditation+fmri&btnG=) has many open source papers on the topic.